# correlating between prediction result to label

Tags: python, numpy, keras, scikit-learn, text-classification

I've a keras model that predicted the following results:
(it's a multi-class problem with 6 possible classes)

`[[0.44599777 0.00667355 0.10674711 0.02558559 0.29180232 0.12319366]]`

so given the above results the model predicts the 1st class - but I know it's wrong.

I was able to achieve a ~92% accuracy:

```
Epoch 1/10
1128/1128 [==============================] - 18s 15ms/step - loss: 1.3685 - accuracy: 0.4596 - val_loss: 0.6238 - val_accuracy: 0.7785
Epoch 2/10
1128/1128 [==============================] - 17s 15ms/step - loss: 0.7200 - accuracy: 0.7373 - val_loss: 0.4055 - val_accuracy: 0.8467
Epoch 3/10
1128/1128 [==============================] - 17s 15ms/step - loss: 0.4994 - accuracy: 0.8200 - val_loss: 0.3284 - val_accuracy: 0.8772
Epoch 4/10
1128/1128 [==============================] - 17s 15ms/step - loss: 0.3966 - accuracy: 0.8568 - val_loss: 0.3100 - val_accuracy: 0.9043
Epoch 5/10
1128/1128 [==============================] - 18s 16ms/step - loss: 0.3428 - accuracy: 0.8810 - val_loss: 0.3044 - val_accuracy: 0.9102
Epoch 6/10
1128/1128 [==============================] - 39s 34ms/step - loss: 0.3075 - accuracy: 0.8915 - val_loss: 0.2970 - val_accuracy: 0.9184
Epoch 7/10
1128/1128 [==============================] - 25s 22ms/step - loss: 0.2779 - accuracy: 0.9035 - val_loss: 0.3051 - val_accuracy: 0.9226
Epoch 8/10
1128/1128 [==============================] - 19s 17ms/step - loss: 0.2663 - accuracy: 0.9069 - val_loss: 0.3207 - val_accuracy: 0.9261
Epoch 9/10
1128/1128 [==============================] - 19s 17ms/step - loss: 0.2514 - accuracy: 0.9138 - val_loss: 0.2855 - val_accuracy: 0.9311
Epoch 10/10
1128/1128 [==============================] - 20s 18ms/step - loss: 0.2331 - accuracy: 0.9196 - val_loss: 0.3352 - val_accuracy: 0.9263
Test loss: 0.33516398072242737
Test accuracy: 0.9262799024581909
```

Below is how I'm doing the prediction:

```
bug_name = '51859'
issue = conn.issue(bug_name, expand='changelog')
candidate_bug = Bug(issue, connections_dict)
candidate_bug.extract_all_info()
data = candidate_bug.get_data_as_df()
data = data.drop('group_name', axis='columns')

free_text_tokenized, _ = prepare_free_text_inputs(data, data)

model_inputs = [free_text_tokenized]

res = model.predict(model_inputs)
print(f'expected: {get_group_by_bug_owner(candidate_bug.get_owner())}')
# Generate arg maxes for predictions
print(res)
classes = np.argmax(res, axis=1)
print(classes)
print(np.unique(y_train))
class_index = classes[0]
print(np.unique(y_train)[class_index])
```

and here's the output:

```
expected: D
[[0.44599777 0.00667355 0.10674711 0.02558559 0.29180232 0.12319366]]
[0]
['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F']
A
```

... so I'm afraid my problem is I don't know to "assign" those results to the labels.
I've tried multiple attempts (where I know what the prediction should be) and it always misses the expected result.

Also - I'm using `LabelEncoder` as follows:

```
    
# prepare target
def prepare_targets(y_train, y_test):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(y_train)
    y_train_enc = le.transform(y_train)
    y_test_enc = le.transform(y_test)
    return y_train_enc, y_test_enc

y_train_enc, y_test_enc = prepare_targets(y_train, y_test)
```

What am I missing? Am I using the wrong the wrong list (`y_train`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question (for whoever's gonna be introduced by it).

2 Issues I've found:

1. I've (very mistakenly) triggered the transformers on the predicted data (`fit_on_text`) and it's a big no no! - one's must use the same transformer that was already fitted via the trained data.
2. the labels are encoded in the `LabelEncoder` that was originally used before training the model, so I've created a dict to map each label as follows:

```
# prepare target
print('preparing lables')
le = LabelEncoder()
le_name_mapping = {}

le.fit(y_train)
le_name_mapping.update(dict(zip(le.transform(le.classes_), le.classes_)))
print(le_name_mapping)
y_train_enc = le.transform(y_train)
y_test_enc = le.transform(y_test)
```

later on I've used it on the prediction results:

```
res = model.predict(model_inputs)
selected_class_index = np.argmax(res, axis=1)[0]
print(selected_class_index)
print(f'actual: {le_name_mapping[selected_class_index]}')
```